# Ограничение входа на сайт php

Tags: php

Нужно ограничить вход на сайт пользователю после третьей неудачной попытки.

Реализация может быть любой, желательно самой простой.

Comment: Капчу на страницу логина поставьте, а то у вас ни кто вообще не войдет на сайт при массовом переборе паролей у всех пользователей сайта.

Answer (score 1):

в чем проблема? при каждой попытки входа смотрите в переменную  $_SESSION['n']. Если сессия пуста присваиваете значение один, если значения один то делаете +1...

> $_SESSION['n'] =  $_SESSION['n'] + 1

если 2 то тоже делаете +1 если же три то блокируете. Если не знаете о сессиях то лучше изучите их по лучше. Если хотите прямь очень надежно то нужно с куки возится но и это не так тяжело ибо принцип один и тот же

Comment: И упадет ваш сайт, так как все отведенное место на диске забьет сессиями ;)

Comment: @Visman ну тогда с куки придется иметь дело

Comment: Сессии свой ключ записывают в куки как раз. Так что с куками тоже не чего не выйдет. Боты, которые подбором паролей занимаются, каждый раз просто без кук стартуют, отсюда и бесконечное создание сессий.